# T-SQL MAX Window Function not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  
    j.inv_num,
    CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE) AS [CostedDate],
    MIN(CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY j.inv_num ORDER BY CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE)) AS [FirstCostedDate],
    MAX(CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY j.inv_num ORDER BY CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE)) AS [LastCostedDate]
FROM 
    dbo.JobCost AS j WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    J.INV_NUM = '353197'
```

Here is the result

```
inv_num CostedDate  FirstCostedDate LastCostedDate
--------------------------------------------------
353197  2023-12-13  2023-12-13  2023-12-13
353197  2023-12-21  2023-12-13  2023-12-21
353197  2023-12-21  2023-12-13  2023-12-21
```

I took out the `[Costed Date]` from the query and did a group by j.inv_num.  It worked as expected.  However, I need the 3 "CostedDate" values that the inv_num was inserted into this table along with the MIN & MAX.

I thought the first row in the result set would have '2023-12-21' as the "LastCostedDate".

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Hi - so what was the actual SQL you ran, the result you were expecting, the result you actual got and the source data that generated the result? Please update your question with this information

Comment: You want to remove the `order by` so that it will look at the entire window.

Comment: The `with (nolock)` hint is not the automatic "go faster" switch you think it is, and you should probably stop using it. If there were such an easy performance win, don't you think it would already be enabled?

Comment: Why do you have ORDER BY in the frame definitions? That restricts the rows being processed and gives you a cumulative min / cumulative max (which make very little sense). Just remove the ORDER BY cmshsea from the frame clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is returned based on the default window frame which is between unbounded preceding and current row. To get the results you want you can specify the window frame explicitly by adding the following after your "order by"

```
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked!!  I need to read more... ;o)

Comment: The better solution is to take the `order by` out completely including the frame. You simply don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer works, as others mentioned, it's much better to just remove the frame and ORDER BY from your window function, since you want to look at the whole picture, like this:

```sql
SELECT  
    j.inv_num,
    CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE) AS [CostedDate],
    MIN(CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY j.inv_num) AS [FirstCostedDate],
    MAX(CAST(j.inserteddatetime AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY j.inv_num) AS [LastCostedDate]
FROM 
    dbo.JobCost AS j WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    J.INV_NUM = '353197'
```

When you add an ORDER BY in the aggregated window function, it creates a "framed" or rolling version, which looks back or forward when calculating max value, the way your code is written, it will take MAX of the dates it has seen *so far*, which doesn't get you what you want.